# EF Core Query not keeping OData query in mind

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I am creating an OData endpoint using the NuGet **Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData** within my *ASP.Net Core* website.

I had the idea to not make my database models public and map them using the *LINQ Select* function, to have more control about which properties are able to be shown to the outside, such as who created what.

In the future some more logic will be added to the *IEnumerable* because of permissions granted on the data.

Everything is working fine; I am able to get, filter and expand data on my *ODataController*. Except for one thing I noticed using the debugging options for *Entity Framework Core*; everything I send to my *ODataController* is being done in memory and not via an expression to *Entity Framework* as I expected. It requests **everything** each time. Of course, as the grows, this will become more and more a problem over time.

Some code resembling what I am doing

```cs
   public class ExampleModel {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

    public class ExampleDbModel{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExampleRepository {
        public IEnumerable<ContentItem> Get(string userId)
        {
            return this._dbContext.Example
                .Select(ExampleMapper.Map) // Mapper is pure property to property in this example, same names
                .Where(e => e.UserID == userId); // Permissions will be more complex
        }
    }

    public class ExampleController : ODataController
    {
        // Constructor, properties, DI, ...
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_exampleRepository.Get(SomeStaticVariableForUserId));
        }
    }
```

When calling the controller I always notice following query being done by Entity Framework Core

```
    SELECT [ExampleDbModel].[Id], [ExampleDbModel].[Name]
        FROM ExampleDbModel
```

Even when I am doing *localhost:5050/odata/examplemodel?$select=id*, it still performs the same query loading **everything**.

I am wondering what I am able to do to translate my OData queries straight to *Entity Framework Core*, to load as less as possible.

Comment: The data is being store in a file (database) not inside VS.  So how can you use just CORE?  The has to be a query to your database.  The data isn't  in memory.

Comment: The SQL I posted is logging by Entity Framework Core, that query is done on the SQL Server. But the select I have done to my OData Endpoint however is not translated into my SQL, so my context is loading data and the OData logic is executed onto the data I loaded into my memory.

Comment: Revert your query. Put the `.Where` in front of `.Select`, not after it. Since in your select you are mapping to a different type, `where` will be run on your OData type, not on your persistence (EF Core Entity model) type, hence EF Core can't translate it and will fetch all data and filter in memory on your projected model (type returned from `.Select` expression)

Comment: I did a test without the  ``` .where ``` and it still performed the same SQL.

Comment: yea rofl... When you remove the where it of courses fetches everything, because you have no conditions. Do what I told you: `this._dbContext.Example.Where(e => e.UserID == userId).Select(ExampleMapper.Map);`

Comment: I think you misunderstood me; I meant it performed still the same query no matter what OData filtering or selecting I am performing. What I am trying to do is my OData query string being reflected into the SQL Entity Framework Core is executing, to load as less data as possible from my database. 

It shouldn't select all fields / records when I performed a $filter or $select.